# Specify location of volumes in docker

Tags: docker, volumes

I need to create a container specifying the location of volumes (not a bind mount).

The container has a volume /var/www, is possible to choose the location on the host machine? (i want to save in /data/www not in /var/lib/docker....). I can't do with -v (bind mount) the /var/www folder has data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't do with -v (bind mount) the /var/www folder has data.

The first order of business would be to get those data on your host (in your host /data/www): run your container, and `docker inspect` it in order to get the path of the volume it uses (the one in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/...`): you can copy those files onto your host.

Then you can bind mount that host `/var/www` folder to your container.

But the better practice remains to use volumes (with the new 1.9+ `docker volumes` API), and mount it with `--volumes-from`.